# Finding mean in linked list

Tags: language-agnostic, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I know the method to find the middle element in singly linked list by going through it only once.

Is there some way to find the *Mean* of the elements in a list?

Comment: What do you mean my 'Mean'?  What do the list elements contain?  Can the contents be added together?

Comment: mean usually means the average. do you mean the median? or just the element at the in middle (according to lists size) of the list ?

Comment: you iterate it using 2 pointers; once that goes on every 2 element and one that goes one by one; when the first one gets to the end the second one is the middle

Comment: Ah yeah, I know how to find the middle element. As @user1121883 gave the method. But that's for the median.

Comment: I want to find the Mean of a linked list with n elements. I don't know where it ends, I only have the link to the next element. In similar fashion to how the middle element was found, is there a way to efficiently(not just dumping all the elements into an array for example) find the average value of all the elements. And yes of course, they can be added together

Comment: Well, if it's a circular list, then you know you've reached the end when you get back to where you were.  If the list is not circular, and you only have one element and its forward link, it is not possible to find the median or mean, (even assuming the elements support addition, comparison and division), because you cannot retrieve the earlier elements in the list.  I'm sorry, but your question is lacking in detail.  If, for example, the list contains integer values and you have access to the root of the list, it's trivial to iterate the list, accumulate the values and keep a count.

Comment: Ah. How foolish. How blind I was. Trivial indeed. I would vote for deletion of this question, if it would not prevent someone else from embarassing themselves similarly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments I suppose you are asking about arithmetic mean (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean#Arithmetic_mean_.28AM.29 )
Also if you know how many elements are there you can get rid of count.

```
    Node current = root;
    double sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while (current != null) {
        sum += current.el;
        count++;
        current = current.next;
    }
    System.out.println(sum/count);
```